# how can I apply User-defined function to get distance in ParalleDisr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to calculate vector distance using paralleDist package applying user define function. Below is example from manual.

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
# Use RcppXPtrUtils for simple usage of C++ external pointers

library(RcppXPtrUtils)

# compile user-defined function and return pointer (RcppArmadillo is used as dependency

euclideanFuncPtr <- cppXPtr(
  "double customDist(const arma::mat &A, const arma::mat &B) {
  return sqrt(arma::accu(arma::square(A - B)));
  }", depends = c("RcppArmadillo"))

# distance matrix for user-defined euclidean distance function (note that method is set to "custom")

parDist(matrix(1:16, ncol=2), method="custom", func = euclideanFuncPtr)
```

I Tried to modified UDF to below but I have no knowledge in wrapping C++. Can somebody help me to transform below code  to fit into above code?

```
Cosine_simil<- function(x, y) {
  similarity <- sum(x * y) / ( sqrt( sum(y ^ 2) ) * sqrt( sum(x ^ 2) ) )
  return( acos(similarity) * 180 / pi )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CosineFuncPtr <- cppXPtr(
  "double customDist(const arma::mat &X, const arma::mat &Y) {
  double similarity = arma::dot(X,Y) / ( sqrt( arma::dot(Y,Y) ) * sqrt( arma::dot(X,X) ) ) ;
  return(acos(similarity) * 180  );
}", depends = c("RcppArmadillo"))
```

how can be pi (constant) expressed?

Comment: You can use the existing `#define` via  `M_PI` or use for example `constexpr double mypi = std::acos(-1);`.

Comment: Pleasure.  Maybe edit it into your nice answer (which I upvoted) ?  `M_PI` may be easiest if we all dislke the macro nature :)  -- and here Armadillo also has `arma::datum::pi`  which is elegant and concise.